# nz-switch is not working correctly due to update with value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, ng-zorro-antd

```
<form [formGroup]="businessFoodHygieneForm">
  <div class="box p-4 d-flex jc-between ai-center">
     <span>
        Food Hygiene Link
     </span>
     <label>
      <nz-switch
      class="switch-middle ms-2"
      formControlName="foodHygieneLink"
      (ngModelChange)="onFoodHygieneChange($event)">
      </nz-switch>
  </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

**ts component:**

```
foodHygieneLink: new FormControl(''),

this.businessFoodHygieneForm.patchValue({
  foodHygieneLink:
    selectedBusiness?.foodHygieneLink,
});

onFoodHygieneChange(status: boolean): void {
    this.foodHygieneLink = status;

    const body = { foodHygieneLink: status ? 'Yes' : 'No' };

    this.bizStore.dispatch(
       businessAction.updateBusiness({
          body: body,
          bid: this.bid,
       })
     );
   }
```

I try to update using `nz-switch` and updated successfully but the switch button is not working if the switch is updated with "No". It should be off but always on.

Comment: Hi, *switch button is not working if switch is update with No it should show switch off but always show switch on*, the update you mentioned is through the click on the UI, or update through the component? Can you reproduce the issue on StackBlitz? Thanks.

Comment: hi @YongShun, you can find the whole code here: https://codeshare.io/OdQw7N I couldn't share on StackBlitz it has ngrx stores etc. so i just share the whole code on codeshare please check this one

Comment: Okay, I create a simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpcmuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), but unable to reproduce your issue that the switch button is not working. Maybe you can fork this project and modify to reproduce your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect is that possibly your `foodHygieneLink` value from the observable is either 'Yes' or 'No' instead of the boolean value.

Thus the `<nz-switch>` will be set to open when the value is `No`.

You can solve it by converting the 'Yes' or 'No' to a boolean value before setting the value to the `foodHygieneLink` FormControl.

```js
this.businessFoodHygieneForm.patchValue({
  foodHygieneLink:
    selectedBusiness?.foodHygieneLink === 'Yes',
});
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpcmuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)